# OpenLayers loading a GML file from an other site

Tags: javascript, openlayers, same-origin-policy, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I'm having difficulties loading a GML file into OpenLayers. I've stripped down the problem to the following :
- copy/past the example at : http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/behavior-fixed-http-gml.html
- replace all links to absolute

This results in the following file/code that I run from localhost (file:///) :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <title>OpenLayers Vector Behavior Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;

            function init(){
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
                var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "OpenLayers WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'}
                );

                var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/gml/polygon.xml",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML()
                    })
                });

                map.addLayers([wms, layer]);
                map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    -3.92, 44.34, 4.87, 49.55
                ));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <h1 id="title">Vector Behavior Example (Fixed/HTTP/GML)</h1>
        <div id="tags">
            vector, strategy, strategies, protocoll, advanced, gml, http, fixed
        </div>
        <p id="shortdesc">

            Vector layer with a Fixed strategy, HTTP protocol, and GML format.
        </p>
        <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
        <div id="docs">
            The vector layer shown uses the Fixed strategy, the HTTP protocol,
            and the GML format.
            The Fixed strategy is a simple strategy that fetches features once
            and never re-requests new data.
            The HTTP protocol makes requests using HTTP verbs.  It should be
            constructed with a url that corresponds to a collection of features
            (a resource on some server).
            The GML format is used to serialize features.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the GML is not displayed (everything else works great). I have no errors in the console but status 200 OK for the request (both in FF console and FireBug Network tab).
What I am missing? Same origin policy failure should show up some error, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does give an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in Chrome.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/gml/polygon.xml.
>   Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not
>   allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

For FF it does give a 200 response code as you stated, but the response contains no data.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/F76Hp/3/

Comment: The response contains no data in FireBug but does in Wireshark, so I was going for a bug in Firebug.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer. Any suggestion on how to proceed ?

Comment: You could use a proxy, for example get the request using jsonp: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//openlayers.org/dev/examples/gml/polygon.xml%27

Comment: I did understand why it works : the yahoo server returns the following header :
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0):

As to protect users from scripts sending information to faraway servers, there is a "same origin policy", which states that you can only receive data through HTTP requests from the same server as the page you are currently viewing.

This explains then why wireshark has the information, and firebug doesn't: The browser disallows the transfer of the information.

JSON-P is a trick to get around this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

If you don't have access to a JSONP source or don't want the JSONP approach, you will have to use a proxy, which will forward your requests to the faraway server and return the information as if it came from your own server. The browser will then not be able to tell that the communication is ultimately going to a faraway server and will allow the HTTP requests.